# Combining @page with other selectors

Tags: css-paged-media, antenna-house

I have a CSS that contains elements that should appear conditionally.

For most elements, this is easy: I have an attribute attached to the body element, and I can use that in the CSS:

```
body[data-var-draft=Draft] .heading1 {}
```

That doesn't seem to work for @page elements though:

```
body[data-var-draft=Draft] @page {}
```

leads to an error message in Antennahouse Formatter (6.6).

I've seen more constraints for @page rules:

```
@page titlepagesection, @page tocsection, @page chaptersection {}
```

doesn't seem to work either.

Is it/should it be possible to combine @page with other selectors?

Answer (score 1):

An `@page` rule is selected by the `page` property value.  To select a particular named page in a particular context, set the `page` property value in the rule for that context:

```
@page draft {
  background-image: url('draft-watermark.svg');
}

body[data-var-draft=Draft] {
  page: draft;
}
```

There is an illustrated example in Chapter 3, Page Layout, in 'Introduction to CSS for Paged Media' available at https://www.antennahouse.com/css/.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, because that leads to duplication of all my @page rules...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't make a page rule inherit/cascade from an arbitrary other page rule. Assuming that a 'draft' page just adds a watermark or similar, have you considered putting the draft content in a 'running' element that's used in a page-margin box? The styles for the running element and/or the page-margin box could specify a width, height, and z-index so that it looks like the page background.